# Prestashop add Category from query

Tags: mysql, categories, prestashop

i must to create a script for import some category from another e-commerce. I need to insert the category using query in mysql. I have create a script and this add the category. In Admin panel i view the new category. But, if i go on the e-commerce, i not view this in the sidebar on left where there are category tree in the default theme.

Also, i have try to add a category from the admin panel and This can be seen on the sidebar in e-commerce. Then, I have deleted all the row from the database but the category And yet visible.

Help me :)

I apologize for my terrible english

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the default prestashop function managing the category creation. Don't use any custom query directly, create a new Category object, fill all needed fields and save it. You may need some extra informations, so take a look at the AdminCategoryController to see what is needed.

In the same way, don't delete category in the database, they are not only stored in the "category" table. Create a new category object with the category id as parameter :

```
$categorytodelete = new Category($id_category);
$categorytodelete->delete();
```